# iAds throw an error quickly (XCode 4.3.1, iOS5, Storyboard)

Tags: objective-c, ios5, storyboard, iad, xcode4.3

Trying to test iAds from XCode 4.3.1. Without thinking much of it, I started using a storyboard, however all the examples of iAds I find use the XIB file only.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_iAds_into_an_iOS_5_iPhone_App#Displaying_the_Ad
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkMhWPh6fzM
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hsjSCM9JJrM

Even the iAds Suite is built on XIB file.

I'm pretty new at ObjectiveC, so I may have overlooked something obvious. But is that normal that using these examples fail onto a storyboard?

I could post code, but honestly that's the same as the YouTube examples.

Comment: This is the error I get, if it helps:

`2012-04-24 13:37:42.272 iAdTest[1131:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named ADBannerView'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13c8022 0x1559cd6 0x1370a48 0x13709b9 0x3334a3 0x333383 0x233cad 0x333c6e 0x33367b 0x333383 0x233105 0xd91fc 0xd9779 0xd999b 0x38401 0x38670 0x38836 0x3f72a 0x10596 0x11274 0x20183 0x20c38 0x14634 0x12b2ef5 0x139c195 0x1300ff2 0x12ff8da 0x12fed84 0x12fec9b 0x10c65 0x12626 0x28bd 0x2825)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)`

Answer (score 2):

Add iAd.framework to your target